# Knockout and Rails: populate viewModel from rails object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, knockout.js

This is probably an easy question: Can I populate my knockout viewmodel using a rails instance object?  For example, I have an edit page at mysite.com/person/1.  The controller finds that person and the view can use @person to render its data.

Can I use @person to populate my viewModel?  Like:

```
self.name = ko.observable(@person.name);
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, but you'd have to output the variable with erb e.g.

```
ko.observable("<%=  @person.name %>");
```

Generally however, you don't want to pass specific variables to specific observables, you want to pass the resource itself to a new I stance of the view model, and then set the view model variables from that, I will update with a better example when I get to a computer, but basically:

```
ko.applyBindings(new viewModel("<%= resource.to_json.html_safe %>"));
```

Update with better example

A person view model I would have structured roughly like this, note the parenthesis, Im not sure exactly why they are needed but if I remember correctly it doesen't work without them.

```
var personViewModel = function(person){

  var self = this;
  self.first_name = ko.observable(person.first_name);
  self.last_name = ko.observable(person.last_name);
  self.friends = ko.observableArray(person.friends);

}

person_json = <%= (@person.to_json.html_safe) %>;

ko.applyBindings(new personViewModel(person_json));
```

However, I like to use coffeescript for my view models these days, as a class for each view model, here is the same-ish code (working, rough equivalent, using class instead of funciton) in coffeescript.

view_models/personviewmodel.js.coffee

```
class PersonViewModel
  constructor: (person) ->
    @first_name = ko.observable(person.first_name)
    @last_name = ko.observable(person.last_name)
    @friends = ko.observableArray(person.friends)

window.PersonViewModel = PersonViewModel
```

And then in your actual view below the form its being attached to.

```
person_json = <%= (@person.to_json.html_safe) %>;

ko.applyBindings(new PersonViewModel(person_json));
```

Comment: This is helpful, but I am wanting to access the `@person` instance variable in my viewmodel.js, not my view.html.erb.  Is this possible?  You seem to be accessing `@person` in your view, not your .js file.

Comment: No thats not possible, not is it a good idea, even if it were. Your .js files are compiled at runtime, or when your assets are precompiled. That is why you need to create a view model that can be instantiated, and then pass it the data it needs in the view.